# Do we have to value possibilities just because they are possible?

Tags: ethics, justice

I want to specify my question to theism (it should apply to all ideas) as an example. Some people believe in theism. The sole reason why they believe is because someone else believes it too and everyone goes along with it. If someone tells me that I can't be 100% certain that there is no god I'm very perplexed. Of course I can't be 100% certain but there is a lot I can't be certain about for example conspiracy theories or unicorns.

We all accept that unicorns are imaginary and that conspiracy theories are made up. And if you try to use these / bring them up in a conversation it is not taken seriously, with good reason. Thanks to critical thinking we know that this is so unlikely to be true that we don't think about it. But the same thing can't be said about theism.

If enough people believed in a conspiracy theory and then started to say "how can you be 100% sure it didn't happen this way" this would lead to a big problem.

A solution would be to only consider/value *ideas* that can be proven or are likely.

Do we have to value/consider ideas just because they can't be disproven?

Is there any literature on this subject? What do you think about this?

Comment: -1, this does not come close to making sense. "The sole reason why they believe is because someone else believes it too and everyone goes along with it." -- have you tried asking believers why they believe? This is ***not*** true, and you don't provide argumentation. Many believers if not most have the feeling there's something they cannot grasp, but something very real. A consequence of that is that you cannot apply something that holds for conspiracy theories to religions.

Comment: @Keelan but you would agree that people only believe because of someone else who 'thought' them. they grew up with it. One guy was the first one to tell these stories. You perfectly address the problem im talking about. Its not ok to say anything against religion because it is something holy and untouchable but when it started it was pretty much comparable to a conspiracy theory. Both see stuff without evidence and people who believe it dont think critically enough.

Comment: cont... with the integration of theism into our society we are forced to respect it even though it was made up by a human to answer question in a unscientific way... by making the answer up. I dont feel like valuing the believe that we were created by a super being just because other people believe it....

Comment: Re. "you would agree that people only believe because of someone else who 'thought' them ... One guy was the first one to tell these stories". A believer would tell you it's not that someone started telling stories, but that there was a divine revelation or the like. This is significantly different, and with the claims you make in this question you're jumping to conclusions.

Comment: tough im not concerned about the things someone else thinks are true. im concerned about if i have to value idea just because someone thinks they are true whether that is theism, a unicorn or a conspiracy theory. do i have to consider an idea just because there is the possibility that it could be true?

Comment: I don't know. I do know that you're jumping to conclusions. That's the only thing I'm pointing out to you.

Comment: Well of course not, you as a human, are capable of doing just about what ever you would like. The value you place on theism is pretty apparent. So where is the issue? You already had your answer. Are you even open to other possibility's? I think people believe because the stories resonate with some feeling within them. Some people "go through the motions" because it was the environment in which they were raised. But here is the thing. Your belief that they are wrong, is just as valid and provable as there belief that they are right. It is very ok to say many things against religion.

Comment: cont... look at bands like "slipknot" who are famously anti christian. They aren't in jail or anything? or heck, how about "bad religion" bam, its right in the name! I figure that you are talking about islam. Because who is it that decrees this "its not ok to say anything against religion?" It sure isn't politicians or lawmakers... However, islam is globally renown for its tremendous ability to overreact to criticism.  Sure the catholics and the church of england at one time in history were the same way, but that outlook doesn't fly in a modern world.

Comment: Book Of Morman... not only criticizes the latterday saints, but flat out sings a song about how backwards and downright STUPID the faith system seems to people outside of the church... and not only is it NOT punished or banned... it was celebrated, given awards, and constantly sold out theaters across a country. I do apologize if you feel that you live in a world where your anti theism makes you a target or social pariah. I feel even worse if you do indeed live as a part of a community or country where that type of stuff goes on. But it is not the way most of the world works.

Comment: @Bob no i dont live in a non secular society and i was targeting christianity. I most certainly dont value any sort of theism or alike. my problem is that it is tolerated. People can say & claim whatever they like to and in an argument just say that you cant disprove it. We have buildings with the sole purpose of 'teaching' religion and praying to a god. Why? because everyone goes along with it.

Comment: 1. the 'everyone goes along with it' sentiment explains all societal norms ever... So you are upset by the fact that some people out there argue poorly? "sole purpose" uuhhh, really? Not to serve as a gathering place to hold community meetings to get to know everyone? Not to serve as a food dispensary to homeless people? No... just everyone coming together to fellate some hippy who got himself nailed to a tree. Your problem is that it is tolerated? Wow... It isn't as though that argument wins. Churches are not recruiting people by saying "god is love, you can't prove otherwise"

Comment: @Bob do you think churches are needed to feed the homeless or build a good community? isnt there a better way? you perfectly point out the problem i have. Religion is not the best answer to any problem there is. Why is it still done? A social state can provide better for the needy because of its authority. And how are you supposed to hold community meetings when some people despise some religions and think their own is the best let alone people who arent theistic? In my eyes everything a religion does besides praising and teaching a god can be done in a better way.

Comment: This is all spiraling out of control. I think that religion was indeed A solution to many problems that we, as a species, used to have. Wonderful point, "isn't there a better way." Yes, for many if not most if not ALL the theoretic issues. Some other function of society has sprouted up to tend to that need. However, you make a lot of assumptions and leaps in logic. Yes faith is dangerous, Yes religion is often selling a metaphysical unknown. But so far you still hinge your argument on, "they try to end arguments with fallacies" and "It solves no problem i have or know of" Which is weak logic.

Answer (score 1):

One does not have to do anything but considering what is possible vs what is probable seems fitting here.  A meteor could crash on my head in 5 minutes but I am not going to speak my last wishes and prepare my last meal at this time.  In other words, it seems proper to weigh the probability in determining the value placed on a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer would be yes. If it was a physical possibility, then it becomes a valid possibility. You then start to get into probability. I agree, the probability that unicorns exist, is outstandingly low. However, it cannot be said with 100% truth that they do not exist.

A note about conspiracies and conspiracy theory's: Conspiracies are quite real, and non imaginary. A conspiracy led to the assassination of president Lincoln. A conspiracy led to the attacks on september eleventh...
Conspiracy Theory's are quite often over exaggerations of doubt, rumors, and hearsay. That being said, many of them end up being total crap. While others are completely justified.

The problem you refer to, i believe is "the tyranny of the masses" [wiki article about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyranny_of_the_majority) Where basically enough people, believe or impose, one school of thought or ideology, to the point where it becomes law or "right" or "fact." And you're right. It would be a big issue.

Now the "solution" to this issue... I am not certain. However i think that at least within the contextual framework of theism, it would at the very least, be considered rude or disrespectful. To disregard someones "possibility". Regardless to how improbable we may feel it to be. It opens a very big "can of worms" however. Because then you open the doors to people justifying polygamy and other much worse things. By saying something along the lines of "hey man, thats what my god tells me to do."

So yeah, tough subject to tackle.

I see what you are saying though, with something like theism, we have only faith. So then i ask you, what constitutes proof? or likelihood for that matter. Does the fact that X number of people "believe" in Y faith, affect the likelihood of it being factual? We get back to the tyranny of the masses... however, even though the process can be distorted or warped towards validating a falsehood. It is also the foundation of our scientific knowledge and understanding of everything... "If enough people can run the same test and get the same results... then its fact"

I am not sure if this really answers your question, as much as gives you something to ponder. ::shrugs::

Answer (score 0):

The degree of confidence you have in a belief should be proportional to the likelihood that that belief is true.

If it is 99.99% likely that unicorns do not exist, then I should be 99.99% sure that unicorns do not exist, *even though it cannot be proven with 100% degree certainty that they do not exist*.

So, perhaps one cannot prove that God doesn't exist. But if it is extremely likely that God doesn't exist, then we are warranted in believing that God probably doesn't exist. The fact that we cannot *prove* that God doesn't exist simply means that we shouldn't be committed to the view that it is *impossible* for God to exist. We may still justifiably claim that the existence of God is very unlikely.

Comment: As written, it's basically a raw claim. I would think that most of us function on a slightly more elaborate basis that also looks at the potential cost of error (here we needn't go so far as something like Pascal's wager) but merely consider that I choose not to walk down streets where I estimate a 5% chance of being shot by a stray bullet. (Not because it is likely I will be shot but because the cost of being shot must be weight against the probability of the event -- meaning that 5% even weighs more heavily than say saving a minute on my way home).

Comment: Agreed. Expected utility should always play a role in deciding how to act and what to believe. My point is not that one ought to believe that p if it is very likely that p; merely that one would be justified in doing so. I also think that the first statement I made is true and is consistent with what you're saying. It's possible to be confident that p because it is likely that p (and to be justified in being confident that p), and nonetheless have dispositive reasons for ultimately believing that not-p.

Comment: You should make clear the assumptions you are taking in your answer if you want it to be a good answer. (e.g., you assume we should make these sorts of judgments based on utility calculation and bayesian reasoning)

Comment: @J-Dawg yes but wouldnt it be better (for the state and society) if we can say unicorns and god do not exists because there isnt enough evidence for it? should we tolerate people teaching stuff that is so unlikely to be true and way more likely to be made up to control people? isnt that just being blind and not actually caring?

Comment: @yamm This is an empirical question the answer to which I do not know. The fact that theism is so historied and entrenched may affect whether we should take a hard line against it, supposing it is likely to be false. It may be more productive to teach people how to think critically and reason well so that they may come to informed conclusions about theism and religion on their own. The case of unicorns is more straightforward.